# codeigniter ion-auth activation code not working sporadically

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth, activation-codes

I am using the the Ion-auth registration library for CodeIgniter. Everything was working fine, but now I see some users have problems with the email registration activation system. I have tested it and the email activation code may not work the first few times you try it, but may work on a subsequent attempt.

It works fine on my localhost version. My guess is that the processing time, or the length of the URL may have something to do with it.
The activation code looks like this: http://domain.com/auth/activate/1133/6021ed8cb63ee10cb39d93eb995e852783133412

Server is a Mediatemple DV.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is if the users.activation_code field is populated and matches the code in the activation email.

Comment: Hi Ben. Yes, I checked that and it matches. I originally had the same problem when I migrated to Mediatemple DV, and had to turn off nginx as it seemed it couldn't handle the long URL. Now, it happens sporadically, so its hard to replicate. Next I will test if the model is getting the right info from the auth controller. My backup workaround will be to have a new function that the user can click a link if activate() fails so we can try it again. Great library btw Ben....thanks for sharing it. A few things are over my head, but its worked well overall.